# why Copy Constructor was executed here

Tags: c++

I could not understand why the copy constructor was executed when I just simply create one Object and execute one function.

```
using namespace std;

class Line {
   public:
      int getLength( void );
      Line( int len );             // simple constructor
      Line(const Line &obj);
      ~Line();                     // destructor
   private:
      int *ptr;
};

Line::Line(int len) {
   cout << "Normal constructor allocating ptr" << endl;
   ptr = new int;
   *ptr = len;
}

Line::Line(const Line &obj) {
   cout << "Copy constructor allocating ptr." << endl;
   ptr = new int;
   *ptr = *obj.ptr; // copy the value
}

Line::~Line(void) {
   cout << "Freeing memory!" << endl;
   delete ptr;
}

int Line::getLength( void ) {
   return *ptr;
}

void display(Line obj) {
   cout << "Length of line : " << obj.getLength() <<endl;
}

int main() {
   Line obj(10);
   display(obj);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `display` takes it's `Line` by value (aka by copy).

Comment: "*obj.ptr;" Nice!

Comment: Avoid owning bare pointers. Prefer smart pointers instead.

Comment: Nice question, not sure why it got three down votes.

Comment: I guess that they thought the question is too basic, but I did spend half hour to search answer from google, but I didn't find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function:

```
void display(Line obj) {
   cout << "Length of line : " << obj.getLength() <<endl;
}
```

takes the `Line` parameter by value, which calls the copy constructor when you invoke `display` here:

```
Line obj(10);
display(obj);
```

If you don't want to copy the argument then pass it by reference:

```
void display(Line &obj) {
```

or by const reference if it's not going to be modified:

```
void display(Line const &obj) {
```

Note that passing by const reference requires changing the signature of `getLength` to be const-qualified:

```
int getLength( void ) const;
```

Answer (score 2):

When you pass the `Line` object to `display`, it is passed by value, meaning it gets copied.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a copy here:

```
void display(Line obj)
```

This results in a call to copy constructor. If you want to avoid this, simply pass by reference:

```
void display(const Line& obj)
```

Comment: They'd also need to declare the `getLength` method as `const` so it could legally be called on a const reference (they should be doing that anyway, given that a simple getter shouldn't be mutating the object).

Comment: thank you, why the Destructor ~Line executed two times? I guess copy data should not create a new object.

Comment: Copying definitely creates a new object. That's just what a copy is.

Comment: Because when you create a copy, it results in a "temporary object" which needs to be destroyed as well. So you see 2 destructor calls

Comment: As you can see probably conclude that unnecessary copies are bad, because they result in "temporary object", destructor calls and hence decreasing the performance of your application.